# Initial condition for lasso

Tags: lasso

From what I understand, the LASSO algorithm searches for a vector $x$ that comes close to satisfying $Ax=b$ for given $A$, $b$, and also requires that $x$ has a small $L_1$ norm. It does this by minimizing the quantity $\|b-Ax\|_2+\lambda\|x\|_1$ for several values of $\lambda$.

I was under the impression that every minimizing algorithm needed an initial guess in order to do iterations of some kind. But I have looked around and don't find any discussion about the initial guess to LASSO. The Matlab implementation does not require it.

So my question is whether LASSO needs an initial guess and what is this guess, when it is not provided by the user.

Comment: [This](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Documents/2005_Notes_Lasso.pdf) paper describes some of the optimization techniques for regularized models. Algorithm 1 is a summary of Tibshirani's method for fitting the lasso.  Seems like the inital guess for the weight is the least squares solution.  I suppose this only works in the case when n>p.